# Transformation from CRS EPSG:3857 to ESRI:54009

Tags: python, gdal, proj, pyproj

I am trying to convert from EPSG:3857 to ESRI:54009 and facing some issues (pyproj version -2.6.1).

`ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: crs not found`

`ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create: unrecognized format / unknown name`

`ERROR 6: Cannot find coordinate operations from` EPSG:3857' to `'``

My code as following:

```py
def project_geometry(geom , in_crs = 3857 ,out_crs = 54009):
    inSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()   
    inSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(in_crs)
    outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
    outSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(out_crs)
    coordTrans = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef)
    geom =ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(geom.to_wkb())
    geom.Transform(coordTrans)
    return loads(geom.ExportToWkb())
```

Is there a direct way to do this transformation?

or do I need to use transformation from EPSG:3857 to other CRS and than from that to ESRI:54009?

Also I didn't find transformation files in this pyproj release.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your output CRS is not defined by EPSG but by ESRI. EPSG:54009 does not exist. For ESRI:54009 use ImportFromESRI https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.osr.SpatialReference-class.html#ImportFromESRI.

**EDIT**

User @snowman showed in the comments the way to get SpatialReference by the ESRI code:

```
>>> from osgeo import osr
>>> outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
>>> outSpatialRef.SetFromUserInput('ESRI:54009')
0
>>> print outSpatialRef
PROJCS["World_Mollweide",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Mollweide"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["ESRI","54009"]]
```

Proj does know ESRI:54009. You can check with the projinfo utility: https://proj.org/apps/projinfo.html.

```
projinfo esri:54009
PROJ.4 string:
+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs
```

Proj also knows what operation to use for transforming data between EPSG:3857 and ESRI:54009. That can be verified also with projinfo

```
projinfo -s epsg:3857 -t esri:54009
Candidate operations found: 1
-------------------------------------
Operation No. 1:

unknown id, Inverse of Popular Visualisation Pseudo-Mercator + axis order change (2D) + World_Mollweide, 0 m, World

PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=webmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84

WKT2:2019 string:
CONCATENATEDOPERATION["Inverse of Popular Visualisation Pseudo-Mercator + axis order change (2D) + World_Mollweide",
    SOURCECRS[
        PROJCRS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
            BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
                DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
                    ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                ID["EPSG",4326]],
            CONVERSION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo-Mercator",
                METHOD["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator",
                    ID["EPSG",1024]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8801]],
                PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8802]],
                PARAMETER["False easting",0,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8806]],
                PARAMETER["False northing",0,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8807]]],
            CS[Cartesian,2],
                AXIS["easting (X)",east,
                    ORDER[1],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                AXIS["northing (Y)",north,
                    ORDER[2],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",3857]]],
    TARGETCRS[
        PROJCRS["World_Mollweide",
            BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
                DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
                    ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
            CONVERSION["World_Mollweide",
                METHOD["Mollweide"],
                PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8802]],
                PARAMETER["False easting",0,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8806]],
                PARAMETER["False northing",0,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8807]]],
            CS[Cartesian,2],
                AXIS["(E)",east,
                    ORDER[1],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                AXIS["(N)",north,
                    ORDER[2],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["ESRI",54009]]],
    STEP[
        CONVERSION["Inverse of Popular Visualisation Pseudo-Mercator",
            METHOD["Inverse of Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator",
                ID["INVERSE(EPSG)",1024]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8801]],
            PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8802]],
            PARAMETER["False easting",0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8806]],
            PARAMETER["False northing",0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8807]],
            ID["INVERSE(EPSG)",3856]]],
    STEP[
        CONVERSION["axis order change (2D)",
            METHOD["Axis Order Reversal (2D)",
                ID["EPSG",9843]],
            ID["EPSG",15498]]],
    STEP[
        CONVERSION["World_Mollweide",
            METHOD["Mollweide"],
            PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8802]],
            PARAMETER["False easting",0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8806]],
            PARAMETER["False northing",0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8807]]]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["World"],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for replay @user30184 ! when I try to use `outSpatialRef.ImportFromESRI(54009)` I get an error `    return _osr.SpatialReference_ImportFromESRI(self, *args)
TypeError: not a sequence`

Comment: By looking at the examples at https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/osr/osr_esri.py ImportFromESRI seems to require some sort of WKT as input. It may be easiest to use the reported Proj string `+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs` for defining the out_crs.

Comment: I would recommend `SetFromUserInput('ESRI:54009')`

Comment: Thanks @snowman, I hope I did it right in my edited answer.